# Datagridview bound to object - Making the new rows appear blank

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a Datagridview that changes its content according to a selection the user makes in a listBox.
The DGV consits of 2 comboboxes (Country, Product) and 1 textbox (Quantity).

I've created a class combined of 3 integers.
This class is used as a type of list, which is the datasource for the DGV.
There is also another list containing the prior list, so I have a list of datasources.

The DGV's datasource is a BindingSource that changes whenever the SelectedIndex of the listBox is fired.

My problem occurs whenever a new row is added to the DGV:
I use the BindingSource.AddNew which calls the constructor of the class, but **it must assign values to each item in the class**. That way, whenever I click any cell in the DGV I don't get a blank row.
Moreover, when the BS changes and then returned, another row is added.

What I want to get is a blank row - empty comboboxes and textbox.

Thanks for your help!

The class:

```
    Public Class PoList
    Private _CountryID As Integer
    Private _ProductID As Integer
    Private _Quantity As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal CountryID As Integer, ByVal ProductID As Integer, ByVal Quantity As Integer)
        _CountryID = CountryID
        _ProductID = ProductID
        _Quantity = Quantity
    End Sub

    Private Sub New()
        _CountryID = 1
        _ProductID = 2
        _Quantity = Nothing
    End Sub

    Public Property CountryID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _CountryID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _CountryID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ProductID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _ProductID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _ProductID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Quantity() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Quantity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Quantity = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Shared Function CreateNewPoList() As PoList
        Return New PoList
    End Function
End Class

Private Sub List_AddRow(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AddingNewEventArgs) Handles AllListBindingSource.AddingNew
    e.NewObject = PoList.CreateNewPoList
End Sub
```

Creating a new inner list:

```
AllList.Add(New List(Of PoList))
AllListBindingSource.AddNew()
AllListBindingSource.DataSource = AllList(TableCounter)
AddPoDetails.DataSource = AllListBindingSource
```

SelectedIndexChanged event:

```
AllListBindingSource.DataSource = AllList(AddPoList.SelectedIndex)
AddPoDetails.DataSource = Nothing
AddPoDetails.DataSource = AllListBindingSource
```

Comment: Edit my post. Hope I got all the relevant lines

Comment: Can you supply a snippet of how you create the DGV combobox columns and how the item table looks?

Answer (score 0):

Right, lets see if I can help you. 
As I interpret it you have a list filled with lists. These lists don't know their own identity and is based on the current index in the list.

First of I wouldn't use Bindingsource.AddNew I would add the new object straight to the list instead.

```
AllList(TableCounter).Add(New Polist())
```

This way you know exactly how many objects has been created, by using events you aren't quite sure are you. 
To refresh the list do this:

```
AllListBindingSource.ResetBindings(true)
```

Which will update your DGV with the new line.

Now you need to restructure your class since when you create a new Polist you set a value to nothing. This will crash your table. What you need to do is this:

```
Private _Quantity As String

Public Property Quantity() As String
        Get
           Return _Quantity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
           _Quantity = value
        End Set
End Property
```

Using a string is the only way for you to get a blank textbox, I would recommend you to have 0 as default if you are using Quantity as an integer (which you should). Your constructor needs to be changed to this:

```
Private Sub New()
  _CountryID = 0            
  _ProductID = 0            
  _Quantity = ""
End Sub
```

In your combobox columns you have to add a blank item in the top (I'm guessing your adding them manually), should be possible by having a blank row in the top of the items.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

The things is that these comboboxes are bound to a datatable, and the values cannot be strings - they have to be integers.

Comment: So what you are saying are that you want a blank textbox and blank comboboxes. But you have set the entire thing up so that a blank textbox and blank comboboxes aren't allowed. Do you see the problem in your logic?

Comment: My two cents, either change the setup completely or decide on a default state that you can consider as blank.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same behaviour you get when you bind it to a DataTable. That's when you get the combobox filled with items but displaying the first empty item.